# The local path is “(null)” and it doesn't exist. Check that the project is building the executably correctly

Tags: c, xcode, synctex

I am trying to build the synctex project in xcode 14.3, follow the offical docuement https://github.com/jlaurens/synctex but now when I build the project, the xcode shows error:

```
The local path is “(null)” and it doesn't exist. Check that the project is building the executably correctly
```

this is the full output:

```
Details

An executable path doesn't exist.
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: The local path is “(null)” and it doesn't exist. Check that the project is building the executably correctly.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-09-30 06:07:05 +0000";
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 343469;
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = DBGLLDBLauncher;
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "MacBookPro18,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "13.3.1 (22E261)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.macosx";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 6;
    "operation_errorCode" = 3;
    "operation_errorDomain" = IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = DBGLLDBLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.macosx";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.tool";
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "macosx13.3";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "13.3";
    "sdk_variant" = macos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.3.1 (a) (Build 22E772610a)
Xcode 14.3 (21812) (Build 14E222b)
Timestamp: 2023-09-30T14:07:05+08:00
```

what should I do to fixed this issue? I did not found anywhere to set the local path in xcode.